# Way to mention null-parameter in documentation?

Tags: scala, null, documentation

I am developing a kind of API and wondering which way would be generally preferred to mention about null-parameter:

A. Write such like `@throw NullPointerException if P is null` assuming all method whose doc says nothing about it will accept null-parameter:

```
/**
/* Does something...
/* @param p the paramteter to do something...
/* @throws NullPointerException if p is null
...
```

B. Write such like `this parameter can be null` assuming null-parameter is not accepted without any mention about it:

```
/**
/* Does something...
/* @param p the parameter... this can be null
...
```

In common sense I feel like A is more legit, but it's actually painful to write about it all the time.

Which way would you choose?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option A is clearer and has the added benefit that scaladoc will show the exception properly.

However: it's much better practice and more idiomatic to use `Option` types instead of `null` wherever you can, which is actually anywhere that you're not interfacing with Java code. That way, the type system itself will document that the parameter can be omitted, and the compiler will be able to ensure that you never forget to check for a missing value.

Comment: So, any nullable parameters are supposed to be `Option`, and I can assume the users will understand any parameters which aren't `Option` should not be `null`, and then I don't really need to mention about `NullPointerException` explicitly?

Comment: Yep! That's the gist of it. Here's a quick introduction: http://blog.orbeon.com/2011/04/scalas-optionsomenone.html

Comment: There are also a bunch of convenient ways to deal with `Options` other than doing a bunch of `if` checks, by the way. You can use pattern matching, for example, or you can (often quite elegantly!) treat them as a mini-Collection that can hold zero or one things.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's good to do both.  You should mention if you're going to get a `NullPointerException`.  In the case where a parameter can be null, instead of just saying that it can be null, you should describe what that would mean.  For example

```
* @param locale the Locale used to format dates, or null to use the system's default Locale.
```

Comment: @RyoichiroOka Did you have a "java" tag on this question and edit it off?  I answered it believing it was Java.  I know nothing about Scala, so I'm happy to delete this if anyone comments that it's not appropriate for Scala.

Comment: I'm so sorry :P I did exactly what you said. I just completely forgot that I was working with Scala. But thank you for answering, because I have been wondering the same thing in Java as well :)